# ¿Por que usando flask_login a pesar de conectarme al sistema este se desconecta al azar al realizar un cambio de pagina?

Tags: python, flask

Estoy utilizando Flask para una aplicacion, está desplegada en un servidor Ubuntu con NGINX y GUNICORN.

El problema que ocurre es que aunque entre al sistema correctamente mediante el formulario de login, al querer acceder a cualquier otra página o incluso actualizando la principal varias veces, me manda a la pantalla de login diciendo que no estoy conectado. En los errores del programa puedo observar que el usuario sale vacio, o en el caso de flask_login, Anonimo.

Cabe destacar que usando la aplicacion en mi equipo (window 7) de manera local esta funciona perfectamente.

Quizas puede ser que haya algunos errores de compatibilidad ya que, hubo momentos en que las consultas a mysql daban error por las versiones distintas.

¿Por que ocurre esto?

Agrego **nginx/sites-enabled/wqr**

```
server {
    listen 5002;
    server_name xx.xxx.xx.xx;

    root /var/www/wqr/;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/wqr/wqr.sock;
    }
}
```

Agrego **systemd/system/wqr.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to server WQR
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/wqr
Environment="PATH=/var/www/develop/bin"
ExecStart=/var/www/develop/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:wqr.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Agrego **app.py**

```
# Importando los paquetes
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from flask_admin import Admin
from .admon import MyModelView, MyAdminIndexView
from .config import configure_app
from .contexts import current_user_context
from .errors import page_not_found, crsf_not_found
from .utilities import initialize_data, format_date, format_hour

# Iniciando la aplicaciòn
app = Flask(__name__)

# Configurando la aplicaciòn
configure_app(app)

# Se agregan procesadores de contexto personalizados
# Inyectando current_user
app.context_processor(current_user_context)

# Inicializando la base de datos
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Inicializando la migraciòn de la base de datos
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

# Protección CSRF para validar los formularios
#csrf = CSRFProtect(app)

# Inicializando el administrador de usuarios, con vista personalizada
admin = Admin(app, index_view=MyAdminIndexView())

# Inicializando el administrador de inicio de sesiòn
login_manager = LoginManager(app)

# Incluyendo los modelos para la base de datos
from .data import models

# Configurando la vista de administrador
# 1) Añadiendo las vistas para cada modelo
# 2) Se debe cambiar el endpoint para no generar colisión de nombres de blueprint

admin.add_view(MyModelView(models.WQPDesionizer,
                           db.session, endpoint="WQPDesionizer_"))
admin.add_view(MyModelView(models.WQPScissor,
                           db.session, endpoint="WQPScissor_"))
admin.add_view(MyModelView(models.WQCEquipmentA,
                           db.session, endpoint="WQCEquipmentA_"))
admin.add_view(MyModelView(models.WQCEquipmentB,
                           db.session, endpoint="WQCEquipmentB_"))
admin.add_view(MyModelView(models.User, db.session, endpoint="User_"))
admin.add_view(MyModelView(models.UserRole, db.session, endpoint="UserRole_"))
admin.add_view(MyModelView(models.Machine, db.session, endpoint="Machine_"))
admin.add_view(MyModelView(models.DailyReport,
                           db.session, endpoint="DailyReport_"))

# Importando los controladores
from .routes.user.controllers import user_bp
from .routes.login.controllers import login_bp
from .routes.main.controllers import main_bp
from .routes.register.controllers import register_bp
from .routes.wqpd.controllers import wqpd_bp
from .routes.wqps.controllers import wqps_bp
from .routes.wqcea.controllers import wqcea_bp
from .routes.wqceb.controllers import wqceb_bp
from .routes.daily_report.controllers import daily_report_bp
from .routes.report_management.controllers import report_management_bp

# Definiendo configuraciòn del admon de inicio de sesiòn
login_manager.login_view = "login.login"
login_manager.login_message = "Debe conectarse para poder acceder al sistema"
login_manager.login_message_category = "danger"
login_manager.session_protection = "strong"

# Registrando los blueprint a las rutas pertinentes
app.register_blueprint(main_bp, url_prefix="/")
app.register_blueprint(login_bp, url_prefix="/login")
app.register_blueprint(register_bp, url_prefix="/register")
app.register_blueprint(user_bp, url_prefix="/user")
app.register_blueprint(wqpd_bp, url_prefix="/wqpd")
app.register_blueprint(wqps_bp, url_prefix="/wqps")
app.register_blueprint(wqcea_bp, url_prefix="/wqcea")
app.register_blueprint(wqceb_bp, url_prefix="/wqceb")
app.register_blueprint(daily_report_bp, url_prefix="/daily_report")
app.register_blueprint(report_management_bp, url_prefix="/report_management")

# Registrando manejadores de errores
app.register_error_handler(404, page_not_found)
app.register_error_handler(400, crsf_not_found)

# Inicializando valores por defecto en la bbdd
# Para configurar la aplicación inicializa la base de datos:
# 1) SET FLASK_APP=wsgi ó EXPORT FLASK_APP=wsgi
# 2) flask db init
# 3) flask db migrate
# 4) flask db upgrade
# luego descomenta la inicialiacion de los datos
#initialize_data(db.session, models)
# Luego vuelve a comentarla para evitar errores por duplicados
# Esto en el caso del modo debug

# Definiendo funciones globales para Jinja
def get_role(role_id):
    role = models.UserRole.query.filter_by(id=role_id).first_or_404()
    return role.description

# Registrando las funciones globales en Jinja
app.jinja_env.globals.update(get_role=get_role)
app.jinja_env.globals.update(format_date=format_date)
app.jinja_env.globals.update(format_hour=format_hour)
```

Agrego *login\controllers.py*

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, flash, url_for, request
from flask_login import login_required, current_user, login_user, logout_user
from .forms import LoginForm
from ...data.models import User, UserRole
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse

login_bp = Blueprint("login", __name__, template_folder="templates", static_folder='static')

@login_bp.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(card_id=form.card_id.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash("Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta", "danger")
            return redirect(url_for("login.login"))
        login_user(user)
        next_page = request.args.get("next")
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != "":
            next_page = url_for("main.index")
        return redirect(next_page)
        return redirect(url_for("main.index"))
    return render_template("login.html", title="Iniciar Sesiòn", form=form)

@login_bp.route("/logout", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for("main.index"))
```

Agrego **data\models.py**

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from datetime import datetime
from .. import db
from .. import login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin


class UserRole(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_role'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    access_level = db.Column(db.Integer)
    users = db.relationship("User", backref="users")

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    creation_date = db.Column(db.String(10))
    creation_hour = db.Column(db.String(8))
    card_id = db.Column(db.String(9), index=True, unique=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(35))
    second_name = db.Column(db.String(35), nullable=True)
    first_surname = db.Column(db.String(35))
    second_surname = db.Column(db.String(35), nullable=True)
    cell_phone = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=True)
    home_phone = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user_role.id"), nullable=False)


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```

*Notas:*

1) Lei que la version 0.3.0 de flask_login tenia ese bug de borrar las sesiones, pero en el hilo uno de los mantainers de flask_login agregaba que lo habia corregido.

2) Creo recordar que el sistema funcionaba perfectamente (claro, solo probe conectarme) y este no cerraba la sesión.

Comment: Si localmente va bien y en producción no, suena como a que la sesión creada en un worker no es reconocida desde otro. Quizás la cookie no guarda todos los datos relevantes. Quizás tengas que configurar nginx para que use _sticky sessions_ (que redirija al mismo worker las peticiones de la misma sesión). Faltan datos sobre tu configuración y sobre cómo guardas la sesión.

Comment: Voy a agregar el codigo del servicio creado para nginx/gunicorn y los codigos de la session

Comment: @abulafia corregido

Comment: Por experimentar, prueba a cambiar el valor de `--workers` a `1` en el arranque de `gunicorn`. Si con eso se arregla, tenemos la prueba de que es un problema de la pérdida de sesión al cambiar de un worker a otro.

Comment: @abulafia mañana en el trabajo lo pruebo. Recordé que si hice varias pruebas del sistema pero usando solo gunicorn y el comando bind. Esa configuración del servicio la hice siguiendo el tutorial de digital ocean para servir flask

Comment: @abulafia hasta ahora funciona excelente, podrias agregar tu respuesta? y si es posible explicarme un poco para que funciona workers y sobre ese archivo que estoy creando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En un comentario sugerí que al lanzar `gunicorn` usaras el parámetro `--workers 1`, como un mecanismo para tratar de diagnosticar el problema. Con esa opción parece ser que ya no se pierde la sesión.

Por tanto el diagóstico del problema está claro. Ocurre que al usar `nginx` como proxy inverso, éste redirige cada petición que recibe a `gunicorn`, el cual originalmente lanzabas con `--workers 3` que significa que por debajo instanciaba tres procesos python en los que ejecuta Flask. Cada uno de esos procesos es independiente de los otros y gracias a que son 3 pueden atender hasta 3 clientes simultáneos (mientras uno está "ocupado" calculando la respuesta de un cliente o esperando por una consulta a una base de datos, otro cliente que llegue podrá ser atendido por uno de los que está libre).

Con `--workers 1` pierdes esta posibilidad, y cada cliente que llegue debe esperar a que finalice el que estaba antes que él. En HTTP esto no suele ser mucho tiempo porque las conexiones HTTP son de corta duración, pero cuando hablamos de cientos de clientes por segundo, se nota en una bajada del *throughput* (clientes atendidos por unidad de tiempo), lo que desde el cliente se percibe como mayor tiempo de respuesta.

Es perfectamente posible que un cliente inicie sesión en uno de los workers, pero la siguiente petición que haga tenga que ser atendida por un worker diferente (porque el primero por ejemplo estaba ocupado, o simplemente porque gunicorn decida aleatoriamente a qué worker enviar cada petición).

HTTP no tiene el concepto de "sesión" (este concepto más o menos viene a ser el conjunto de interacciones entre un mismo cliente con el servidor, que usan un mismo "contexto", como por ejemplo mismo nombre de usuario, carrito de la compra, etc. en el fondo un conjunto de variables compartidas entre todas las peticiones de una misma sesión). Ya que HTTP es "stateless" (sin estado) no tiene forma de identificar que dos peticiones HTTP separadas son en realidad parte de la misma sesión. Por eso un worker pudo autenticar al usuario, pero otro no sabe nada de eso.

La solución a este problema es hacer que todos los datos de las sesión se almacenen fuera de los workers. Una opción es que lo almacene el cliente y lo vuelva a enviar en cada petición. Por ejemplo, que viajen en una *cookie*. Tras loguearse el servidor crearía la cookie de sesión y se la enviaría al cliente como parte de la respuesta. Posteriores peticiones del cliente transportarían la misma cookie. Aunque fueran a parar a un worker diferente no sería problema porque ese worker recibiría en la cookie toda la información que necesita (nombre de usuario, id, o lo que sea).

Otra solución es usar un almacenamiento externo en el lado servidor, como por ejemplo en `redis` u otra base de datos. Entonces la *cookie* sólo necesita transportar un *token* de sesión que serviría para recuperar la información de sesión de la base de datos.

Yo creía que Flask por defecto usaba el primer enfoque (la sesión se almacena en una cookie), pero es posible que esté equivocado o que tu aplicación haga algo más que se almacene en variables globales del worker y que por tanto "rompa" la noción *stateless*.

Limitando a un worker el problema obviamente se arregla, pero algo sigue habiendo algo mal, que te impedirá escalar a un mayor número de workers si llegas a necesitarlo.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, lei todo y sobre lo que dices de flask, este SI guarda en una cookie la sesion, leyendo varios hilos sobre flask_login encontre que flask_socketio rompe la sesión (estuve haciendo unas pruebas de unos chats y es posible conectarse con sesiones distintas de socket desde una sola conexion de flask) y estaba otro que es el que nos interesa que comentaba que puede haber una parte del código que invalide la sesion, en el caso de la pregunta le faltaba validar la conexion a una url y por eso pasaba sin tener login. Su problema era distinto pero argumentaba lo mismo que tu

Comment: Añado a esto que en Flask existe la posibilidad de proteger la aplicación con una libreria llamada CRSFProtect la cual es utilizada tambien por Flask_WTForms.
en otra aplicacion que tenia al utilizar esta libreria me generaba problemas en una peticion ajax, al hacer post me decia que no habia token de seguridad creado, leyendo la documentacion explicaba

Comment: Que se debe inyectar el token con javascript porque ajax no consigue obtenerlo ya que no es una peticion realizada con el motor de Flask.
Quizas el problema este basado en ese token, ya que, estoy trabajando todos los formularios con Flask_Wtf y este requiere un token de seguridad, puede que al igual que esa peticion de AJAX, se este borrando el token.
Lo raro seria que el problema ocurra solo en nginx, ya que, en window funciona perfectamente.

Comment: En windows usabas también gunicorn? Porque el problema no es nginx, sino el tener más de un worker.

Comment: Ademas en los servidores configuro la aplicación flask para estar en modo producción, evitando asi la doble ejecucion de la aplicacion (realizado en modo debug), por lo que, no deberia haber problemas de cookies duplicadas (se le presentaba el problema a otro usuario de stack)

Comment: En window gunicorn no, utilize gevent, que permite servir la aplicacion, para window gunicorn no funciona correctamente, esta libreria esta orientada a entorno unix.

Comment: Probando que fuera la configuracion de Flask, encontre la forma de colocar las sesiones con tiempo de expiracion nulo, es decir, cookies de sesion permanente, y de igual manera las borra.

Cuando probe (que te comente en el comentario) solo con gunicorn funciono correctamente, es decir, sin usar el wqr,service

Comment: Sí, lo que me temía. Seguramente los --workers los crea mediante fork() y windows no tiene esa llamada. Gevent es algo muy diferente, ya que no crea varios procesos sino que usa otra forma de programación asíncrona, todo en un mismo proceso. Puedes usar gevent también en producción y matas dos pájaros de un tiro, pues por un lado al ser un solo proceso desaparecerá el problema de la sesión, y por otro al ser asíncrono podrá manejar a varios clientes "a la vez" (puede cambiar de un cliente a otro mientras espera por operaciones de E/S, que son las que representan la mayor parte de la espera)

Comment: creo que opte por gunicorn, ya que, gevent me mantiene una consola y no sabria como reiniciar una app en especifico, en este caso gunicorn se ve mas practico ya que al crear el servicio puedo reiniciarlo y saber especificamente el problema. a menos claro, que con gevent se pueda armar tambien un service. o que pueda cambiar esa linea de ExecStart con gevent, o te pregunto, se podria agregar alli solo el app y que dentro de este gevent ejecute?

Comment: Lo siento, pero no sabría decirte. No conozco como va lo de wqr.service pero a priori no veo por qué no podrías poner en `ExecStart` cualquier otro comando. Incluso puedes hacer que `gunicorn` use `gevent` poniendole la opción `--worker-class gevent` (para lo que tiene que estar instalado con `pip install gevent`)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87106/discussion-between-victor-alvarado-and-abulafia).

Answer (score 1):

--workers 1 por lo visto es la solucion. Al momento de hacer esta modificacion he podido mantener la session y conectarme con diversos usuarios a mi servidor en produccion.
Gracias por la ayuda, me he pasado 2 dias en esto.

Comment: No añadas “gracias” como respuesta. Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), podrás [votar a favor de preguntas y respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) que encuentres útiles. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/340328)